# When updating an AWS Glue Table is it possible to automatically update the partition metadata

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a partitioned S3 bucket. I am reading the data from the partitions using AWS Athena. I create the AWS Glue Table used in Athena via a CloudFormation stack. The relevant part of the stack is shown here

```
S3ServerAccessLogsTable:
Type: AWS::Glue::Table
DependsOn: S3ServerAccessLogsDatabase
Properties:
    CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
    DatabaseName: 
      Fn::ImportValue: S3ServerAccessLogsDatabase
    TableInput:
      Name: s3_server_access_logs
      Description: !Sub
        - AWS GLUE table for viewing server access logs in ${S3Bucket}
        - S3Bucket: !Ref BucketName
      TableType: EXTERNAL_TABLE
      PartitionKeys:
        - Name: bucket
          Type: string
      StorageDescriptor:
        Columns:
          - Name: bucket_owner
            Type: string
          - Name: bucket_name
            Type: string
          - Name: request_date_time
            Type: string
          - Name: remote_ip
            Type: string
          - Name: requester
            Type: string
          - Name: request_id
            Type: string
          - Name: operation
            Type: string
          - Name: key
            Type: string
          - Name: request_uri_operation
            Type: string
          - Name: request_uri_key
            Type: string
          - Name: request_uri_httpProtoversion
            Type: string
          - Name: http_status
            Type: string
          - Name: error_code
            Type: string
          - Name: bytes_sent
            Type: bigint
          - Name: object_size
            Type: bigint
          - Name: total_time
            Type: string
          - Name: turnaround_time
            Type: string
          - Name: referrer
            Type: string
          - Name: user_agent
            Type: string
          - Name: version_id
            Type: string
          - Name: host_id
            Type: string
          - Name: sig_v
            Type: string
          - Name: cipher_suite
            Type: string
          - Name: auth_type
            Type: string
          - Name: end_point
            Type: string
          - Name: tls_version
            Type: string
        InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
        OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
        Location: !Sub
          - s3://${S3LoggingBucket}/s3-server-access-logs/
          - S3LoggingBucket: !Ref S3ServerAccessLogsBucket
        SerdeInfo:
          SerializationLibrary: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe
          Parameters:
            {
              "serialization.format": "1",
              "input.regex": '([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) \[(.*?)\] ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) \"([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (- |[^ ]*)\" (-|[0-9]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ("[^"]*") ([^ ]*)(?: ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*))?.*$'
            }
```

If I update the AWS Glue Table in the CloudFormation template and then update the stack, I now need to run the command `MSCK REPAIR TABLE <table_name>;` in Athena so that the partition metadata will be mapped to the table. If I don't do this last step, there is no data visible when I query the table.

The problem is that I keep forgetting to run the `MSCK REPAIR TABLE <table_name>;` command and others who are not used to the process will definitely forget.

So I'm wondering if there is an automated way to handle this, so that the partition metadata is automatically reloaded when the AWS Glue table is updated?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [partition projection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html)? You can add the partition projection information to CloudFormation as well.